# Comparing two excel sheet in MSexcel 2010

Tags: sql-server, database, excel

I am tring to compare 4 excel sheet with upto 1000 records,in excel2010 there is no compare tool(so i cant try if it works or not),i m also not able to implement vlookup.. i tried online sites..but no success.
Now i m trying to insert value from local excel sheet into MSSQL..for that found given command

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=G:\Test.xls;', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

giving error below.

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Then i changed this command as

```
INSERT INTO mytable values('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=G:\Test.xls;', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

in which 'mytable' is a dummy table with same format as of my excel sheet
which gives error

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research..i found another method..in which I directly imported the whole data of excel sheet into MSSQL.

which can be done as follows:

MSSQL-->object explorer--> Database--> right click on your DB(new or existing) --> Task--> Import Data

Then select MS Excel as Data source,choose file from local-->next
Then choose "MS OLEDB provider for SQL Server" as destination..then two nexts and click on finish.

This will load all the data of your excel file in DBMS..then you can write query for the type of data you want.